# Range of continuous transformation on closes set

Tags: continuity, transformation

let $f$ be a continuous transformation and $F$ closed set.
Prove that the range $f(F)$ does not have to be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example $f(x)=\operatorname{atan}x$ and $f(\mathbb{R})$ is an open interval.

Answer (score 1):

Take a projection $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ which is given by $p(x,y)=x$. So, if you choose the closed set $F=\{(x,y)\mid xy=1\}$ then $p(F)$ is not closed.

Comment: Why F is closed set ?

Comment: you can see that by proving that $F^c$ is open. If still you have problem, ask again

Comment: Still have problem

Comment: did you see that $F$ can be "pictured" in the plane $\Bbb R^2$?